# JavaScript weird undefined string

Tags: javascript, string, object, undefined

I have the following code and what each command returns during runtime below.

This code runs when an event is fired. The event is called `touchend` and is fired once a user removes their finger from their mobile display.

```
console.log(e instanceof Object); //true
console.log(e); // object
console.log(e.direction); //undefined

WGMB.Core.eventObject = e;

console.log(e instanceof Object); //true
console.log(WGMB.Core.eventObject); //object
console.log(WGMB.Core.eventObject.direction); //undefined

console.log(typeof e.direction); //undefined
console.log(typeof WGMB.Core.eventObject.direction); //undefined​
```

However, typing `WGMB.Core.eventObject.direction` in the console returns `"left"`
and opening up `e` I can see the `direction` property as `"left"`.

What is this problem? I've never encountered this before and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Post the context. The fact that at some point in time your code logs what it logs, and at some time in the future you can examine the object in the console and it's different, just means that something happened in the interim.

Comment: It seems like the moment the code is running the object is still not loaded, therefore undefined. Not sure how are you getting the object but try adding a setTimeout to call the object to verify that is the issue.

Comment: This code runs when an event is fired. The event is called `touchend` and is fired once a user removes their finger from their mobile display.

Comment: Could be wrong but I'm not sure why `e.direction` would be populated on `touchend`. It's the end of the touch. Seems more appropriate that it would be on [`touchmove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove) if it was anywhere. Not sure where this property comes from though. Most of the time you have to iterate through the `touches` array of the event for the `clientX` and `clientY` properties to determine a direction.